# How do I restrict router-outlet to only populate a certain portion fo the page with that component?

Tags: primeng, angular-routing, angular13, router-outlet, jpanelmenu

I'm using Angular 13 and PrimeNG 13.  I have this basic component (ContentComponent) where I would like to click an item in the menu and see the corresponding component in the primary content area ...

```
<div>
    <div class="sidePanel">
        <div class="menu">           
            <p-panelMenu  [model]="items" [multiple]="false"></p-panelMenu> 
        </div>
        <div class="main">             
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have defined these PrimeNG MenuItems ...

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.items1 = [{
      label: 'Users',
      items: [
        {
          label: 'Reports',
          id: 'reports',
          routerLink: ['reports']
        }
    ...
      }
```

and I have set this up in my app-routing.module.ts file

```
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
  {
    path: 'content',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ContentComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'reports',
        component: ReportsComponent
      },
```

but when my page with the panel menu is rendered and I click on the "Reports" item, the "ReportsComponent" takes up the entire screen and causes the navigation panel to disappear.  How do I restrict router-outlet to only populate the component in the designated section of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ReportsComponent` should be rendered within the `ContentComponent` based on the routing change, you can change the app's routes as follows:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
  {
    path: 'content',
    // The parent component should be added here:
    component: ContentComponent
    children: [
      // The children's components should be added here:
      {
        path: 'reports',
        component: ReportsComponent
      },
```

Read more about Nesting routes in Angular here:
https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes